# Elasticsearch - recency boost error: 'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [boosts].'

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using the python elasticsearch api to hit a elasticsearch on some data that has the following fields:

```
"id", "dateCreated", "title", "text_body"
```

The "dateCreated" is of the form '2021-09-01T23:09:54.79362+00:00'

I'm running a query against elasticsearch as follows:

```
    body = {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": <query>,
                "fields": ['title^3', 'body']
            }
        },
        "boosts": {
            "dateCreated": {
                "type": "proximity",
                "function": "linear",
                "center": "now",
                "factor": 8
            }
        },
    }
    res = es.search(index=<index>, body=body)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [boosts].')
```

I'm guessing it's having some issue with "dateCreated", but I'm not sure what. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is `boosts` ? Are you trying to use `boost` parameter of elasticsearch ?

Comment: I think it's called 'boosts'? I was copying from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/boosts.html#boosts-recency-boosts

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having the same issue in the Nodejs client

Comment: In a nutshell - the issue was that I'm using "elasticsearch", not "elastic app search" and the APIs are different. I couldn't recall what I ended up doing in elasticsearch, but at least I was able to move passed that once I realized that.